# `matplotlib` colored output for graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

How to output colored graph (each vertex has its own color) using `matplotlib` library for python? Is there any method to adjust specific color to each vertex?

Code example without using colors:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges):
        self._edges = edges

    def visualize(self):
        vg = nx.Graph()
        vg.add_edges_from(self._edges)
        nx.draw_networkx(vg)
        plt.show()

nodes = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'D'],
         ['C', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['E', 'F']]
G = Graph(nodes)
G.visualize()
```

That's how i want to see it:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example so we can understand your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to change colors only for this case or make it more flexible - using *list comprehension*, but AFAIK `draw_networkx` has a parameter which takes a list of strings or for `RGB` tuple of floats, so only what you can do is prepare a list of colors:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, edges, colors):
        self._edges = edges
        self._colors = colors

    def visualize(self):
        vg = nx.Graph()
        vg.add_edges_from(self._edges)    
        nx.draw_networkx(vg, node_color=self._colors)
        plt.show()



nodes = [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['C', 'D'],
         ['C', 'E'], ['D', 'F'], ['E', 'F']]

colors = ['green', 'red', 'red', 'green', 'green', 'red']

G = Graph(nodes, colors)
G.visualize()
```